# displaying success/error messages after form submission - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, message, form-submit

I'm not able to know how to display the success / error messages. Main problem is where to put codes. Here, i'm inserting my code. Please help me to go through it. I'm new to codeigniter, here everything is in well organized. 
Before that, in core php, we pass error/success messages through header('location...'); but, here,it is totally different.

**View** (index.php)

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('welcome/MemberFileUpload');?>
  <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple> <br>
  <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
        {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
        $this->load->library('session'); // Start Session
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        }
 public function member_CAttachments()
 {
     $data['results'] = $this->news_model->member_MAttachments(); 
     $this->load->view('member/templates/header');
     $this->load->view('member/index',$data);
     $this->load->view('member/templates/footer');
    }
  function MemberFileUpload()
    {       
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('FileTitle', 'Title', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
            {
            redirect('welcome/member_CAttachments/');
        }
        else
        {
                $FileTitle = $this->input->post('FileTitle');
                $FileDesc = $this->input->post('FileDesc');
            $CurrentDate=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
            $InsertedFileID=$this->news_model->UploadFileDetails($FileDesc, $CurrentDate,$FileTitle);

            $UploadDirectory='assets/Upload/';
            $TotalUploadedFiles=count($_FILES['files']['name']);

            for($i=0;$i<$TotalUploadedFiles;$i++)
            {
                $UploadedFileName=$_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
                $EncFileName=time().$UploadedFileName;
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $UploadDirectory.$EncFileName))
                    {
                    $this->news_model->UploadFiles($InsertedFileID, $EncFileName);
                } 
            }
            redirect('welcome/member_CAttachments/');
        }
     }
}
```

**Model**

```
class News_model extends CI_Model 
{

        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->load->database();
        }
        public function UploadFiles($InsertedFileID,$EncFileName)
        {
            $MemberData = array(
            'FileID' => $InsertedFileID,
            'FilePath' => $EncFileName
            );

            $this->db->insert('MemberFiles', $MemberData);
       }
}
```

Comment: What error messages, you are not generating any

Comment: yeah, where to place those error / success codes here

Comment: Look at the manual for [Flashdata here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this to your controller:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('response',"Data Inserted Successfully");
redirect('welcome/member_CAttachments/');
```

add this to your view:

```
echo $this->session->flashdata('response');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your upload code redirects to

```
 redirect('welcome/member_CAttachments/');
```

In that template is where you should put your error/success code

Comment: yess. In this function only, i'm redirecting to index.php page.

public function member_CAttachments()
 {
   $data['results'] = $this->news_model->member_MAttachments(); 
   $this->load->view('member/templates/header');
   $this->load->view('member/index',$data);
   $this->load->view('member/templates/footer');
     }

Comment: either 'member/templates/header' or 'member/index' would be the template to have your error / success message code in.

Comment: member/index is the template

Comment: The result of your MemberFileUpload() function should return data to member/index template. You should pass a flag variable (ex: $error = true | false ) that lets you know if the upload was successful or did not complete so you can display that information to the user from the template.